# Random permutation with equal transition probability

Tags: matlab, statistics, permutation, probability

Given x = [1,2,3,4], I would like to have a sequence of 160 numbers resulting from the permutations of x, but with some caveats:

1. no repetition of the same number [ex 1,1]
2. equal transition probability for each couple

Is there a Matlab function I can exploit?

Comment: Permutation of 4 object? Should be 4! = 24, not 160

Comment: This I know!
Still, my final sequence has to encompass 160 numbers.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is meant by "equal transition probability for each couple".

Comment: What is a sequence of numbers resulting from permutations of x? Do you mean a sequence of vectors where each vector is a permutation of x?

Comment: Yes. With those caveats.

Answer (score 0):

```
close all
clear all
clc

x=[1 2 3 4];
Nx=numel(x);
N=10^6; % lenght of sequence
S=nan(1,Nx);
idx=1;
S(1)=x(idx);
xrest=x(x~=x(idx));
for iN=2:N

    idx=randi(Nx-1);
    S(iN)=xrest(idx);
    xrest=x(x~=xrest(idx));
end
%%
sum(diff(S)==0); % check for repeats
%%
pairs=nchoosek(x,2); % get forward transitions
pairs=[pairs;pairs(:,[2,1])]; % add reverse transitions
Count=nan(size(pairs,1),1);
for iPair=1:size(pairs,1)
   Count(iPair)= numel(find(S(1:end-1)==pairs(iPair,1) & S(2:end) ==pairs(iPair,2)));
end
%%
bar(Count) % equal transition probabilities
```